# Python, Tkinter how to give optionmenu its own windows when pressed

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I have a drop down menu girded on my calculator and i have it set so that there is 3 menu items. What i want to happen is that when one of the menu items is selected it opens a toplevel window describing that item menu and each one is a different menu because they contain different things how can i code this to happen. Im stuck with setting it so that it opens different window for when a different one is slected.

```
def change_dropdown(*args):
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("READ")
    toplabel = Label(top,text= "Lmao", font = ("Helvetica", 13))
    toplabel.grid()
    button = Button(top, text="Dismiss", relief=FLAT, font = ("Helvetica", 10, "bold"), fg = "ghostwhite", bg = "black", width = "30", height = "2", command=top.destroy)
    button.grid()
    top.focus()


def popmenu():
    global tkvar
    tkvar = StringVar(master)

    choices = {"About","Colour themes", "Contact",}
    popupMenu = OptionMenu(master, tkvar, *choices)
    popupMenu.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 5, sticky=W+E+S+N)
    tkvar.set("About") 
    tkvar.trace("w", change_dropdown)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, you want something like this...

```
def change_dropdown(*args):
    if tkvar.get() == "About":
        # open About window
    elif tkvar.get() == "Contact":
        # open Contact window
        ...., etc
```

**Complete example**

Each Toplevel window is a window like the root window and you put widgets on it just like on master.

I changed the code a bit to make it more readable from my point of view; I lifted the main window (master) code from the function. I put font specs in the beginning to make the Labels and Buttons code shorter. I changed the Dict choices to a Tuple which feels more natural. I gave the OptionMenu a width to keep it from changing size with chosen selection.

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.geometry('300x150+1000+50')
info = Label(master, text='Press "p" for popup menu')
info.pack()


# Fonts
H13 = ("Helvetica", 13)
H10B = ("Helvetica", 10, "bold")

def change_dropdown(*args):
    top = Toplevel()
    if tkvar.get() == "About":      # About window
        top.title("About")
        toplabel = Label(top,text= "The About window", font = H13)
        toplabel.grid()
        button = Button(top, text="Dismiss", relief=FLAT, font = H10B,
                        fg = "ghostwhite", bg = "black", width = "30",
                        height = "2", command=top.destroy)
        button.grid()
        top.focus()

    elif tkvar.get() == "Contact":      # Contact window
        top.title("Contact")
        toplabel = Label(top,text= "Contact form", font = H13)
        toplabel.grid()
        button = Button(top, text="Dismiss", relief=FLAT, font = H10B,
                        fg = "ghostwhite", bg = "black", width = "30",
                        height = "2", command=top.destroy)
        button.grid()
        top.focus()

    elif tkvar.get() == "Colour themes":    # Color themes window
        top.title("Colour themes")
        toplabel = Label(top,text= "Choose color theme", font = H13)
        toplabel.grid()
        button = Button(top, text="Dismiss", relief=FLAT, font = H10B,
                        fg = "ghostwhite", bg = "black", width = "30",
                        height = "2", command=top.destroy)
        button.grid()
        top.focus()

tkvar = StringVar(master)

def popmenu(event):
    top = Toplevel()
    choices = ("About","Colour themes", "Contact")  # Tuple or List instead of dict
    popupMenu = OptionMenu(top, tkvar, *choices)
    popupMenu.config(width=15)     # Otherwise width varies with option
    popupMenu.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 5, sticky=W+E+S+N)
    tkvar.set("Pick one") 
    tkvar.trace("w", change_dropdown)

master.bind('p', popmenu)
master.mainloop()
```

This is a very simple interface, but if you plan on making it more complex I strongly suggest you read up on Object Oriented Python. Keeping track of globals gets difficult pretty quick.

Comment: and how to make the window like thats made for about and made for contact. How to edit those windows and type text on them etc and i want them to be two different windows because contact and about is different

Comment: Updated with example.

Comment: when i run this code it always opens a window even when i havent selected a tab. The tab box is at the top of my calculator and when im launching and without evening choosing a tab in the box it opens a window how can i fix this

Comment: Well, you will have to call the menu from somewhere and I didn't think this would be an obstacle for you. I changed the code so now I first create tha main window and call the popup menu from there. But how do you want it to behave? You'll have to think about that. Maybe what you want is a regular popup menu. It's possible to use the Tkinter menu for that.